# How to integrate Edraw Office Viewer Component with zk without using javascript?

Tags: java, zk, viewer

I want to open & edit the document online and saved the updated document in my respective location.So I am using Edraw Office Viewer Component to view and edit the document in a browser.In my previous application, this component is working fine with javascript but in my new application I am using ZK.So I want to know how this component will integrate with Zk without scripting language.

Is it possible to integrate this component with zk without using script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that without JavaScript because Edraw Office Viewer totally depend on scripting language.